# Ionic: Passing array elements between controllers

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a controller & view which computes and displays a specific element. When I click a button on the view, I want to open another which shows more information about the item.

What is the best way to pass the element to another controller for display?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could build a service which get data from one controller and passing it to the other, like so:

```
.factory('shareData', function(){

    var finalData;
    return {
        sendData: function(data) {
            finalData = data;
        },
        getData: function() {
            return finalData;
        }
    }
});
```

Another option you have is to create a shared varraible in your main controller('app' controller in ionic)

```
.controller('app', function($scope){
    $scope.data;
})
.controller('app.controller1', function($scope){
    $scope.data = "Hello World";
})
.controller('app.controller2', function($scope){
    console.log($scope.data); //Hello World
});
```

Comment: Hey Matan. Coming from a C++ background, your first option looks the nicest to me! Many thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, would the parameterised method be an option too? E.g. declaring a state which has: url: "/myUrl/:myId"

Comment: yes you can do the same thing in the url params way, although I dont have much previous experience with that method.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another option besides those included by Matan Gubkin is including the array in the $rootScope: this way you will be able to access it from everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

@Matan Gubkin idea is close, but you should use  the service to get the specific item that you desire.

```
.factory('shareData', function(){

  var finalData = ["Hello World",'more data'];

  return {
    sendData: function(data) {
        finalData = data; 
    },
    getData: function() {
        return finalData;
    },
    getItem:function(_id) {
       return finalData[_id];
    }
  }
});
```

then in setting up your controllers

```
.controller('app.controller', function($scope){

})
.controller('app.controller-list', function($scope,shareData){
    $scope.data = shareData.getData();
})
.controller('app.controller-detail', function($scope,$stateParams,shareData){
    // use stateParams to get index
    console.log(shareData.getItem($stateParams.index)); //
});
```

setting up your routes

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
 $stateProvider

  .state('app', {
    url: "/app",
    abstract: true,
   controller: 'app.controller'
  })

  .state('app.controller-list', {
    url: "/list",
  })

  .state('app.controller-detail', {
    url: "/detail/:index", // <-- pass in index as stateParam
  });
   // if none of the above states are matched, use this as the fallback
   $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/list');
});
```